# Next.js fetch a token from an api on initial render and store it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm building an application using next.js, there is a need to fetch a guest token from an api and set in the cookie as it would be needed throughout the application. So the first thing I want is the token to be set in the cookie before any page is loaded.

I'm migrating from react, there this logic was there in the app.js file and it was a single page application.

I tried putting the logic in getServerSideProps in the home page, it worked fine and the cookie was set, but the issue was if the user go to any other page first directly, the cookie won't  be there. To achieve that we have to duplicate this code in that page as well. (which I don't want as there are lot of pages)

Then on further research, I came to know that we can use getInitialProps in the _app file, that fetches the initial data for all the pages but it comes with a warning (This disables the ability to perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to be server-side rendered.) Not sure if it would be ideal for this case.

Is there any other solution, like some kind of wrapper we can use on top of _app to fetch the token server side and store it.
**I'm new to next.js, please help me with this.**

Comment: Use either [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-with-data) or [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) depending

Comment: @JaredSmith that's what I'm using, but I want the data for all the pages and don't want code duplication.

Comment: If your pages are using `getServerSideProps` then [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization#how-it-works) is not a concern since it's already disabled for those. You can just use `getInitialProps` in `_app` or abstract the logic into a reusable function that you call in each page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the same server side logic to all the pages you could use [next middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) or [next custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server).

Consider that middleware use a subset of the nodejs runtime features so to perform http request you have to use the custom server. AIf you want you can then left to the middleware just the set/check of the cookies.

Comment: So where the cookie would set, can you explain with example ?